# My Facebook application's Javascript doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

My Facebook application contains Javascript that works in Firefox and IE, but aborts in Chrome.

In the Javascript console it gives several errors.including:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object onloadhooks has no method 'replace'
```

There are similar errors complaining about a missing method for 'toLowerCase'.

**Stop Press** Problem no longer occurs. Chrome appears to have patched the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Chrome developers ([Issue 1717](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1717)), this is an issue with the Facebook FBJS library, and something they plan to escalate to Facebook.

I don't have a workaround for this in the meantime.

Comment: Hilarious: A javascript bug in Chrome is the web site's fault? Hahaha. Why does chrome say it is safari? Surely *that* is the real bug.

Comment: How do you know it's a Javascript bug in Chrome? Just because it works across a lot of browsers doesn't mean it's not a bug in the sites code.

Comment: @rq, I can see this is a tricky area. My reading is Chrome is very much like Safari in most regards (because they both use WebKit to render the HTML), so saying it is Safari-equivalent probably saves a lot of incompatibilities, but it is different in at least one respect, so maybe you are right.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in Chrome. Please vote to close as no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook itself has problems in Chrome.  On some pages the buttons just don't work (like deleting a news entry on your own page).

Comment: Agreed, but Facebook manages to limp along in Chrome anyway. I don't want my application to make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

i ALWAYS have problems with java anything in google chrome. sucks because i actually like the browser.

double you tee eff

Comment: java anything? I don't follow.

Answer (score 0):

Then how come facebook's applications like 'flixter movies' is able to show FBJS's extended permissions dialog for publishing it to user's and friends wall.?

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in Chrome. Please vote to close question as no longer relevant.